# Emacs remove last directory in a string

Tags: regex, elisp

Suppose, I have a string with directory name: "/sites/all/modules". And I want to remove the last component of it, producing: "/sites/all". I tried, creating a function, but it returns: "/sites/all/modules".

```
(defun remove-last-dir (dir)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "(.*)/.+" "\1" dir))

(print (remove-last-dir "/sites/all/modules"))
```

Comment: An analogous method in php seems to work for me, but I'm not familiar with `elisp` at all.  Perhaps you should use `file-name-directory` (or some other `dirname` analog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ELISP> (directory-file-name (file-name-directory "/sites/all/modules"))
"/sites/all"
```

`file-name-directory` gets the directory component of the given path. Emacs considers paths ending in `/` to be directories, so the return value will have a trailing `/`

`directory-file-name` returns a non-directory version of the path (which means it strips a trailing `/` from the value, if there is one).

Note that if your original argument was (or could be) `/sites/all/modules/` then you would want to call `directory-file-name` on that first (as otherwise `file-name-directory` would just return the original value, because the "directory component" of a directory path is itself).

Comment: @philis It's ok with the slash. How to check, what solution is the fastest? I saw, that file-name-directory is in C source code. So, it must be pretty quick. Where can I see it's source?

Comment: @user4035  why don't you simply measure the time to run, say, 10000 times each implementation of the function?

Comment: user4035: Provided you have the source code available, you can use `M-x find-function` to see any function's source (elisp or C), or just click on the link in the `describe-function` help buffer. If that's not working for you by default, you can download the [sources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/#Obtaining) and then configure the `find-function-source-path` variable.

Comment: @S4M I executed each function 100 000 times and measured the elapsed time. Your function: 3.313, my function: 1.11, philses simplified function `(file-name-directory "/sites/all/modules")`: 1.25. So, my function is the fastest, and will be marked as a solution.

Comment: Apart from speed (unless it is strictly in the critical path, that I don't think so in this case) I prefer this solution because it is more semantically explanatory. It does what expected, and more declarative. It also uses a library function, intended for doing so. This can be slower now, but could be optimized in the future. Also, it can contemplate different directory separators, depending on the underlying architecture, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote you some code in ELisp that should do the trick:

```
(defun remove-last-dir (dir)
  (let* ((splits (cdr (split-string dir "/")))
         (res (mapconcat 'identity (butlast splits) "/")))
     (concat "/" res)))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution works. But are there more efficient ways to do it? Without splitting a string to list and then joining back a copy of it without the last element?

Comment: @user4035 I have no idea. To be honest, I consider myself as an emacs(Lisp) noob, and just happened to see your question, and the answer I posted is for me the most natural way to do it. I'd be curious to know if there is something more efficient though. Out of interest, what do you need it for?

Comment: I made it :P. I wanted to automatically load TAGS file for my custom Drupal modules, when I am opening the module file. It will be stored 1 dir above the module file itself.

Comment: user4035: `(locate-dominating-file default-directory "TAGS")`

Answer (score 1):

Wrote the efficient solution:

```
(defun remove-last-dir (dir)
      (string-match "\\(.*\\)/" dir)
      (match-string 1 dir))

(print (remove-last-dir "/sites/all/modules"))
```

Prints:

"/sites/all"

Answer (score 1):

While [@phils's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15046138/596361) is correct and idiomatic for Emacs without third-party libraries, if you work with files and filepaths in your Elisp frequently, i recommend installing [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) library, which introduces a vast amount of file and directory related functions. [`f-dirname`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-dirname-path) is what you need:

```
(f-dirname "path/to/file.ext") ;; => "path/to"
(f-dirname "path/to/directory") ;; => "path/to"
(f-dirname "/") ;; => nil
```

Check out other functions as well, if you need more control over paths.